# Filter large Json File on JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leaflet

I have large json file and I am working to plot it on map. I can't load the file, that why I have to request data every time I zoom in or move the map

The file is

```
 var data3d = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [[
                    [13.37356, 52.52064],
                    [13.37350, 52.51971],
                    [13.37664, 52.51973],
                    [13.37594, 52.52062],
                    [13.37356, 52.52064]
                ]]
            },
            "properties": {
                "wallColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
                "height": 500
            }
        },{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [[
                    [13.37356, 52.52064],
                    [13.37350, 52.51971],
                    [13.37664, 52.51973],
                    [13.37594, 52.52062],
                    [13.37356, 52.52064]
                ]]
            },
            "properties": {
                "wallColor": "rgb(255,0,0)",
                "height": 500
            }
        }]
    };
```

I wanna build a function that filter data that I need to plot

```
function onMapMove(e) { requestData(); }
```

Then I should build a function this way.

```
function requestData() {
  var bounds=map.getBounds(); // I get these values from the browser
  var minLongitudeLat=bounds.getSouthWest(); //minimum Longitude Latitude
  var maxLongitudeLat=bounds.getNorthEast(); //maximum Longitude Latitude

// Here what I should to select data between 
['+minLongitudeLat.lat+','+minLongitudeLat.lng+'],['+maxLongitudeLat.lat+','+maxLongitudeLat.lng+'];

}
```

should I write JQuery PostJson function.

```
    jQuery.postJSON(link,
   function(data){
     return //
        });
```

**UPDATE:** (Answer Comment)
I am trying to build ajax call,
thisFile.json is the file that contain abovemontioned data3 content

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'thisFile.json',
            data: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data){
                filteredData=[]
                 for (var i = data.features.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {     
                if((data.features[i].["geometry"]["coordinates"][0][0]>minLongitudeLat.lat && 
                   data.features[i].["geometry"]["coordinates"][0][1] <minLongitudeLat.lng ) &&
                   (data.features[i].["geometry"]["coordinates"][0][0] > maxLongitudeLat.lat &&
                   data.features[i].["geometry"]["coordinates"][0][1]< maxLongitudeLat.lng)) {filteredData.append(filteredData) }
return filteredData;
          }; 
            },
        });
```

or should I write python script to make the filtering

PythonScript.py , but how to get and post data ?

```
import json
print "Content-type: application/json"
// Should I read here the whole data 

// local_file = open("/tmp/download_file.json", "w") 

// How to pass parameters to filter json file ?

print json.dumps()


 $.getJSON("/PythonScript.py ", function(data) {
        // Here we get data
    });
```

Comment: You can't get only part of the file, it's all or nothing when using **$.getJSON()**. If you  need to filter it and return only parts of the JSON, do it on the serverside and create an ajax function to your own serverside script that does the filtering.

Comment: Thanks Man ! I don't have a great experience in Ajax, Can you give a push by mentioning if I am in the righ track or no. Check update code

Comment: Or should I write python script that does the filtering on the backend

Comment: Depends, if that's the entire JSON file, you can just get it with ajax and keep it in a variable on the clientside, if the JSON is really a lot bigger, filtering  on the serverside is probably better, it's really up to you to decide

Comment: Thanks ! one last thing, I am lost. I don't know how to communicate between python script and js. how can I pass parameters (in this case : minimum Longitude Latitude / max Longitude Latitude). Can you check teh second update and if you don't mind give a hint on how to implement that. Thanks in advance

Comment: I really don't know any python, at least not how to run a python webserver ?